# drive one output with two inputs vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am starting with VHDL. My code is pretty simple, I am switching LEDs on/off with a process which takes clk rising edge and counts circles of the clock in "t" variable:

```
entity leds_vhdl is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           led1 : out  STD_LOGIC;
           led2: out  STD_LOGIC;
           change : in STD_LOGIC);
   end leds_vhdl;

architecture Behavioral of leds_vhdl is

constant t1s : integer := 50000000;

begin
process (clk)
variable t : integer := 0;
begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        t := t + 1;
        if (t > 5*t1s) then 
            t := 0;
        if (t <= 3*t1s) then
                led1 <= '0';
                led2 <= '0';
        elsif (t > 3*t1s and t <= 5*t1s) then
                led1 <= '1';
                led2 <= '1';
        end if;
end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Now, I want to modify the LEDs when different states of the input "change". For example, if "change" is '1', how could I make change the LEDs? (led1 = '1', led2 = '0' for example). ¿It would be possible to do in the same process, or better do another one?.
I´ve been trying but I´ve been having so many problems in synthetizing phase.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your code is not doing what you expect it to do. Because the second if-statement is encapsulated in the first if-statement, t is always set to 0 before the second statement. Thus the LEDs always stay at 0.

Comment: For sinthetizable code, you should preferably make t a signal instead of a variable.

Comment: And yes, you should do it in one process.

Comment: I´ve corrected my code and now is working properly. Thank you!